# Automatic chage password of pages after some time

Tags: plugins, pages, password

Hello any idea how to make a page I publish to chage the password after 2 days automatically (I am looking for a plugin or something else I can implement)? Right now I am using the pages to present something to my clients but then I want to not have access to it after 2 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE. Plugin recommendations are considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, so here's an action approach to the problem.

You could use [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) to schedule a daily event for resetting page password. You can use [wp_schedule_event()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) to schedule your custom event.

In your event callback, use first [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) with [password parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#password-parameters) to get all protected pages. Then loop through found pages and update their passwords with [wp_update_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) as password is saved in the `post_password` post property / posts table column.

If you want the new password to be something random, you can for example use [wp_generate_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) to generate it.